# Implementing gotoDate issue in fullcalendar in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar AngularJS version to make a scheduler calendar what. I want when a user clicks on a date that the calendar should show that specific date in the view in fullcalendar..

But the very initial issue is that I am not able to use fullcalendar goto function.

I am using this fiddle to get fullcalendar in AngularJS:
http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/o7fh0htz/1/
**in this fiddle i made a few changes** to get uiCalendarConfig object so that i can use gotoDate funtion.

**Added myCalendar in div:**

```
 <div
    calendar="myCalendar" ui-calendar="calendarConfig" ng-model="eventSources">
            </div>
```

And inject **uiCalendarConfig** in controller:

```
angular.module('calendarDemoApp').controller('calendarController', ['$scope','uiCalendarConfig', function ($scope, uiCalendarConfig)
```

Now I can get `console.log(uiCalendarConfig.calendars)` and I can see:

```
myCalendar
:
m.fn.init[1]
```

But when I do `console.log(uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar)` myCalendar got undefined.

Ultimately I want to use gotDate function please help me out.. I am breaking my head!